# Why do we override initializers in Swift?

Tags: swift, inheritance

From [Swift's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html):

> Unlike subclasses in Objective-C, Swift subclasses do not inherit
>   their superclass initializers by default.

But then it says:

> When you write a subclass initializer that matches a superclass
>   designated initializer, you are effectively providing an override of
>   that designated initializer. Therefore, you must write the override
>   modifier before the subclass’s initializer definition.

Coming from a Java background where constructors are not inherited, I don't understand how this works exactly. Why would we be overriding an initializer that isn't inherited by default? It seems to me like constructors, initializers would be implicitly named after the class itself and can be overloaded in the subclass (for example, class `Dog` in Java would only have constructors with name `Dog`). But I don't understand this idea of overriding a parent initializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclasses might not inherit their superclass initializers "by default", but they can be inherited (e.g. if you don't supply any designated initializers, you will automatically inherit all of the designated initializers of the superclass ... see [Automatic Initializer Inheritance](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID222)).

Consider a `Dog` subclass called `Chihuahua`: If you don't implement any designated initializers in `Chihuahua`, you automatically inherit the `Dog` initializers with no extra code on your part. But if you do need to override it for some reason, do so and you just need to call a `Dog` designated initializer from your `Chihuahua` designated initializer. And if your `Chihuahua` initializer has the same signature as a `Dog` designated initializer, then you must explicitly supply the `override` keyword.

Comment: Ah, this makes a lot of sense, thank you! So the override is only applicable when the initializer is inherited from the superclass?

Comment: Yes, or to be a tad more precise, [as the docs say](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-NoLink_137), "As with an overridden property, method or subscript, the presence of the `override` modifier prompts Swift to check that the superclass has a matching designated initializer to be overridden, and validates that the parameters for your overriding initializer have been specified as intended."